# How to get unique variables from nested object?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a problem to getting unique variables from nested object :

```
var chartData = {
  labels : [ " some data..."],
  datasets : [ {
      label: "nice label",
      fill: false,
      data : 
      [ 'more data ... ',]
   }
```

I want to access to the `data`

```
let unique = [...new Set(chartData.datasets.data)];
console.log(unique);
```

This method doesn't work.
I want to use this unique variables to the Y-axis in chart.js like :

```
yAxes: [{
          display:true,
          labels:unique,
          type:"category",
...
```

Comment: This should be closed as it is due to a simple error that is unlikely to help others...for some reason it won't let me vote to close again (I originally marked this as a duplicate and then spotted the simple error being made).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly accessing the `data` property because `datasets` is an array.

```
let unique = [...new Set(chartData.datasets[0].data)];
```